# Display details from database using ajax/jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

getStudents.js

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: "displayStudents.php?branchCode=1",
    datatype:"JSON",

    success: function(obj){
        for(var i=0; i<obj.length; i++){
            $("ul").append(obj[i].name)
        }
    }

})
});
```

displayStudents.php

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
$branchCode = $_GET['branchCode'];
$list = mysqli_query($con, "Select * from student where branchCode = '$branchCode' ORDER BY rollNo");
$result = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($list)){
    $result[] = array("RollNo"=>$row['rollNo'], "Name"=>$row['name']);
}

header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

The php file 'displayStudents.php' is sending the json correctly but I'm not able to display the names of the students.

Comment: Change $("ul").append(obj[i].name) to $("ul").append(obj[i].Name) since that's how you've labelled it in php

Comment: Why aren't you able to?  What prevents this from happening?  When you debug, what specifically is the problem?  What does your browser's debugging console tell you?  What is the actual response from the server?  When you step through in the browser's debugger, what fails?

Comment: Thanks @LoveenDyall.